# MongoDB Insert Async Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm using mongodb in a websocket nodeJS application. At the moment I have only one client, which is constantly sending data. I get randomly duplicated key (_id) errors. These errors are strange since they occur, while the next element is inserted and the one with the duplicated key is actually stored. (while sending each element only once)

Here is a code snippet of the implementation:

```
var server = ws.createServer(function (conn) {
  conn.on("text", function (str) {
    data = JSON.parse(str);
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {

      if (err) throw err;
        var db = client.db('locator')

        db.collection('locations').insertOne(data, function(err, res) {
              client.close();
          });

        });
    };

  })

  conn.on("close", function (code, reason) {
    console.log("Connection closed")
  })
}).listen(8001);
```

I have already checked if the _id is unique. The duplicated id error says, that it cannot store e.g. _id 7 while the websocket actually received the next element and the element with _id is already stored. I think this problem could be related to the asynchronous anonym functions, but I'm not really sure and I also wouldn't know how to solve this issue, if this is the problem.

**EDIT** here is some example data:

```
{
  '_id': 7, 
  'dataId': 7,
  'timestamp': 152731785.8186,
  'causeOfTransport': "",            
  'location': {
    'pos': {
      'long': 0,
      'lat': 0,
      'altitude': 0
    },
  },

  'connection': {
    'qualitiy': 0,
    'speed': 0
  },

  'device': {
    'software': "v0.0.1"
   }
}
```

Comment: Does `data` have an `_id`?

Comment: Can you give example of `data` you are pushing to `mongodb` ?

Comment: This happens using _id explicitly and when using the standard key generator of mongoDB (ObjectId) without _id in the data.

Comment: I added an example document.

Comment: just remove `_id` while sending data to `mongo db`, it creates `_id` itself.

Comment: Then I had the same issue with the generated ObjectId. Which was the reason to create the `_id` by myself.

Comment: `Mongodb` always creates unique Id's. can you send the complete `error`

Comment: `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: lockator.locations index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5b033a88e7546b31a047fb32') }`

Comment: when this error is cmng? if you are not sending `_id`?

Comment: This error is coming when not sending an `_id`. The error is similar when setting the `_id` as shown in the example document.

Comment: Is it plausible, that it is an asynchronous issue? I think the strangest part is, that the error occurs on a document, which is successfully stored, but the next one is missing in the DB.